# IF NOT EXISTS then INSERT else show message not working

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a table with 'reference' in it, the idea is that if a reference exists already, then it doesn't insert. If it doesn't exist then it does insert. But this code just doesn't insert either way. Assist please.

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=127.0.0.1 dbname=XX user=XX password=XX") or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
$query = "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT reference FROM card WHERE reference = '$reference')
INSERT INTO staff (reference, first_name, last_name, address1, address2, address3, address4)
VALUES ('$reference', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$address1', '$address2', '$address3', '$address4')";

$result = pg_query($query);
    if (!$result)  
{  
echo "Customer update failed!! This ID might already be registered with us. Please go back and check the spelling of your email address.<br><br><input type=\"button\" value=\"Go Back\" onClick=\"history.go(-1);return true;\">"; 
die; 
} else  
{  
echo "Customer update successful; ";  
}  

pg_close();
```

Comment: You have SQL-injection vulnerability in there - never use raw variables to build a query text. You should be using PDO and prepare.

Comment: yes I know, but not worried about injections at the moment, will prepare sql properly on the live system, just need to get it working first.

Comment: That never ever happens.

Comment: Always happens here, nothing goes live until it's been secured

Comment: Use pg_query_params() to avoid SQL injection and avoid dynamic unsafe SQL in the first place. Security isn't a add-on, it should be standard behavior.

Comment: no argument with that, I just don't have the skills, my code goes from me to a guy who does the security. But I'm slowly learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a [column as Unique](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-unique.html). Then Insert and don't worry for the existence of that row. It returns FALSE if it already exists.

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
    $db = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=yourdbname charset=utf8","username","password");
    $query=$db->prepare("
        insert into staff (
            reference, first_name, last_name,
            address1, address2, address3, address4
        )
        select * from (
            select ? as reference, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
        ) as _
        where reference not in (select reference from staff)
    ");
    $insert = $query->execute(array(
        $reference, $first_name, $last_name,
        $address1, $address2, $address3, $address4
    ));
    if ($insert->rowCount() == 0) {
        echo "ERROR: Customer already exists!";
    } else {
        echo "Customer account creation successful!";
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: ".$e;
}
```

Comment: that's beyond me, I haven't used PDO, but I'll look it up and try and work it out from your example, thanks